# Looking for a book about a boy and a girl that could fly

Tags: story-identification

I remember reading a story/stories in the 70's about a boy and girl who could fly using a backpack/pouch that had cords that they had to extend to their hands (this became a crucial item in the story as one of their cords got broken/cut and couldn't fly at a key point in the book).

There were some monsters that they were trying to get away from and I remember that they were following them (while in a car?).  The author mentioned something about "racing the moon" and it comes back to me every time I drive a car on a moonlit night.

Sorry this is so vague but it was a very long time ago.  I remember enjoying the story and would like to pass it on to my Daughter who is a voracious reader like myself.  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this might be *[The Giant Under the Snow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Giant_Under_The_Snow)* by John Gordon

[image: Book Cover]

Comment: That was it thank you so much!!!!!

Comment: Glad that was it!